# A technical question on the category of metric spaces

Tags: metric-spaces, category-theory, closed-map

Consider the category $\mathcal{M}$ whose objects are metric spaces, and maps are continuous injective maps and the subcategory $$^c\mathcal{M} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{M},$$ whose objects are metric spaces and maps are continuous closed injective maps.

Does this inclusion preserve directed colimits and pullbacks?